# What changes can be made to make Matthew happy?

Tags: logical-deduction

When Matthew eats at a buffet, he has one serving of each dish, but never goes back for seconds.

When asked the name of his favorite animal, Matthew lists 26, each starting with a different letter.

What changes can be made to the letters and/or numbers below to make Matthew happy?

```
      4 x 
    7 x x
x x x x x
```

Comment: Is it intentional that we don't know the operator?

Comment: @xylius Yes because that would make the problem too easy

Comment: Okay then, challenge accepted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Matthew does not like repetition. He prefers one of each. Since there are 10 spaces, he would like to use 0-9 once each.

Keep the 4 and the 7 and replace all the x's

> 46 multiplied by 715 = 32890